# Microphone not detected on Acer Swift 5

Tags: audio, microphone, pop-os

I have installed Pop!_OS a few days ago and after many and many researches I finally found how to have the audio detected on Ubuntu (and it was really long and difficult).

The problem is that my microphone doesn't work and is not detected. When I do `alsamixer` and I go in "Capture" it detects nothing.

The only thing I've changed in `alsa-base.conf` is that I added options `snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0` (which makes my audio work). I have in my input devices an "Analog Input" which doesn't work. My PC is an Acer Swift 5, my card is an HDA Intel PCH, and my chipset is a Realtek ALC255. Can someone help me? I have no idea of what to do to make the microphone work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the following line to the last line of the file /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=laptop-amic enable=yes
```

Source:https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmint/comments/fltlrl/no_sound_on_acer_swift_3_with_kernel_53/